# React Antd Button Flickering onHover on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

When I create a button using antd like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';

 export default class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  };
      }

      render () {
          return (
              <Button>Test</Button>
          )
      }

 }
```

Everything works fine.

**BUT if I make a button like the following:**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Button } from 'antd';

     export default class Component extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {  };
          }

          render () {

            const TestButton = (props) => {
                  return (
                       <Button>{props.label}</Button>
                       )
                   }

              return (
                  <TestButton label="Test" />
              )
          }

     }
```

When I hover over the button it constantly flickers like it is is having onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave constantly trigger.

Not sure if there is a way to get around this, but any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: can you make a codesandbox or a jsfiddle, it'd be easier to poke around your code. Also the issue might be in your **Button** component, the one you imported from `antd`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried using the default <button> and also import <Button> from material-ui and all have the same issue.  I will try to put a jsfiddle together with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately it was as simple as changing extends React.Component to PureComponent.

**Face Palm**

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your button outside of your render function.  By creating your button variable inside of your render function, it's creating a new instance of a button on each render, rather than rending the same button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';

export default class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  };
      }

    const TestButton = (props) => {
        return (
            <Button>{props.label}</Button>
        )
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <TestButton label="Test" />
        )
    }

 }
```